# Getting error in 'mongodb-connection-string-url'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am beginner and cannot understand the error message. After running app.js file I am getting following log message.
On some search I found that I have to upgrade my MongoDB but as I am working in windows 7 it is not possible.

```
PS G:\AWebDev\Website\Dance website> node app.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
  throw e;
  ^

Error: No valid exports main found for 'G:\AWebDev\Website\Dance website\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url'
←[90m    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:9)←[39m
←[90m    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:14)←[39m
←[90m    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:22)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\AWebDev\Website\Dance website\node_modules\←[4mmongodb←[24m\lib\connection_string.js:6:41)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m
}
```

Comment: If you get "*error in 'mongodb-connection-string-url'*", then it would be very useful to provide us the failing connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Nodejs to v13.12.0 for Windows 7 resolves the problem.